# How do I modify the DXL code generated by the analysis wizard in DOORs?

Tags: ibm-doors

When I right click the column generated by the analysis wizard, select properties, browse DXL, all options are greyed out. I cannot select "Current", and I cannot find the code used to generate the column. I am unable to see the code, nor modify it.

I need to update the code to create a skip list that skips duplicate objects created through multiple levels of linking.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot select "Current", you probably don't have the permission to write, modify or run DXL code. Contact your administrator and ask for the power "Edit DXL"